# Esp8266: Webserver variable Manipulation

Tags: html, c++, webserver, esp8266

I want to code a webserver witch isruning on the ESP8266. I code in Visual Code with Platformio Addin.

At the moment I can display buttons, and can react on them, but it is extremly slow, and the esp8266 has to send the whole code for the webserver every time new. I've seen some code witch don't need to send the whole code.

How can I make this? Is There away to manipulate some variables of the server?

Flo

Comment: Use Google to search for AJAX and jQuery. There are thousands of examples out there of how to use them to build dynamic web pages.

Comment: Thank you very mutch, you helped me alot.